# Read contents of an excel file which is on the shared drive(size=200MB)

Tags: excel, vba

I need a serious help from you guys. I need to read the contents of an excel workbook which is on the shared drive. The size of the excel workbook is 200MB. I tried to open it in a normal way like these,

```
workbooks.open("Server_path\Server_file.xls")
```

The file did not get open even I waited for 1 hour or so.Then i tried it on the smaller file which is 281KB(it is also an excel file), which is also on the same server and it took roughly 2 mins.

Im aware of dealing such huge files which are on the local drive. But I dont know the faster way to open the excel file which is on the shared drive. Actually Im at india and file is located at london server.So please help me with opening of the file.atleast if I open it I can just capture all the contents into a variant and close it.

But opening the file is a big issue here.Please help me with these.Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using OLEDB connection?

Comment: Not yet! what do you mean by OLEDB connection?

Comment: check this msdn link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx